# Lenovo IdeadPad S10-3c problems

Tags: lenovo, ideapad

Please help me fix these problems because I really like ubuntu 12.04 and I have replaced my windows 7 ultimate for this.

1. Everytime I turn on my ideapad it hangs, but when I insert my usb device that I used for the installation and restart my ideapad, it works. How can I open my lenovo without my usb device?
2. My keyboard doesn't work. I pressed each key and none of it works.

Those are my first two problems. I haven't tried the microphone, speaker and webcam yet because I can't even type a single letter. Please do fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1st problem:  GRUB wasn't installed correctly.  You should install it on your computer.

This is from my other answer.

> To reinstall GRUB:
>
> 1. Boot from a Ubuntu Live CD/USB
> 2. Install `boot-repair` using these commands:
>
>    `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
>
>    `sudo apt-get update`
>
>    `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
>
>    `boot-repair`
>
> [image]
>
> Click "Recommended repair". This will reinstall GRUB in the MBR of the
>   adequate disk(s). Then reboot.

2nd Problem:  Probably a Driver problem.  Find an External Keyboard and plug it in your computer.  It should all work.

To fix it permanently, try installing the proprietary Driver for it.  Go to the **Dash**, search for **jockey**, then click on **Additional Drivers**.  A Windows should open.  Find your keyboard there and click "Activate".

Good Luck!  But next time it would be preferable to separate the Question if it contains 2 or more problems in it.